# Camel SQL component RetreiveGeneratedKeys removing all other headers

Tags: sql, apache-camel, components

I am using camel SQL component for db inserts. I have set RetrieveGeneratedKeys as true in the exchange header. However after the insert, I m able to get the generated value but all other values from my header is lost. I had set quite a few data in my header but once the db insert takes place the header is just having the generated key value and the generates key row count. Is this a bug?? Kindly help

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried with a newer release.

Comment: I am using Camel 2.14.0. I am storing quite a few values in my header but as soon as the db insert happens, the header is just containing Generated Key Value and Generated Key row Count. All other stored values are lost.